# Right aligning money_put results

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get the C++ library to generate properly formatted USD output ($ sign, commas for every 1000s place etc).

I'm close, but I cannot get the right alignment to work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <locale>

using namespace std;

int main() {
   double fiftyMil = 50000000.0; // 50 million bucks
   locale myloc;
   const money_put<char>& mpUS = use_facet<money_put<char> >(myloc);
   cout.imbue(myloc);

   cout << showbase << fixed;
   cout << "A";
   cout.width(30);
   cout.setf(std::ios::right);
   mpUS.put(cout, false, cout, ' ', fiftyMil * 100); // convert to cents
   cout << "B" << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

I'm getting:

```
A$50,000,000.00                             B
```

I want to get:

```
A                             $50,000,000.00B
```

Any ideas why this isn't working?

I'm using the latest Solaris compiler (12.4)

**Update:**
It seems like the issue is with the C++ libraries included with the Solaris compiler. This is the workaround I used:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <locale>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

string getFormattedCcy(double amt) {
   ostringstream os;
   static locale myloc;
   static const money_put<char>& mpUS = use_facet<money_put<char> >(myloc);
   os.imbue(myloc);

   os << showbase << fixed;
   mpUS.put(os, false, os, ' ', amt * 100);
   return os.str();
}

int main() {
   double fiftyMil = 50000000.0; // 50 million bucks

   cout << "A";
   cout.setf(std::ios::right);
   cout.width(30);
   cout << getFormattedCcy(fiftyMil);
   cout << "B" << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of problems--one with your code, another that looks like its in your implementation.

The problem in your code is pretty trivial. Since you're using a default-constructed locale, it should be using the "C" locale, which shouldn't write out the `$` or thousands separators.

That part is easy to fix. Change: `locale myloc;` to: `locale myloc("");` to get a localized locale (so to speak).

I *doubt* that'll fix the justification problem you're seeing though. That looks to me like it's a problem with the standard library you're using. When I run your code (with the correction above) I get what I'd expect:

```
A                $50,000,000.00B
```

That's with Visual C++ though (and despite a compiler that conforms fairly poorly, its standard library is about as good as they come).

Also note that right justification is the default, so the line:

```
cout.setf(std::ios::right);
```

...*should* have no effect (but I suspect you knew that, and added it in the hope of getting it to work when it didn't otherwise).

As far as how to get things to work with the <strike>Sun</strike> Oracle compiler, the most obvious suggestion would probably be to switch standard libraries to one that works better. That leads to another question: whether to try to get a standard library to work with the compiler you're using, or switch to a different compiler such as CLang or gcc. From what I understand, 12.4 was a pretty serious improvement in terms of C++ conformance, but I don't think either the compiler or (apparently) the standard library is really competitive with gcc or Clang yet. OTOH, you may not have a choice, in which case essentially your only route is to build a different standard library with your existing compiler, and hope for the best. If you can't even do that...you could try setting the locale correctly, and just writing the number with `std::cout << fiftyMil;`, and hope it at least gives you commas as it should, then add the currency sign separately.

As an aside, if you do get an updated (C++11 or newer) library, you can use `put_money` to simplify the code quite a bit:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <locale>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    double fiftyMil = 50000000.0; // 50 million bucks
    std::locale myloc("");
    cout.imbue(myloc);
    cout << "A" << showbase << setw(30) << put_money(fiftyMil * 100) << "B";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I think the issue is with the peculiarity of the Oracle compiler. On a side note, myloc; and myloc(""); produce the same results for me.

Comment: If `myloc;` and `myloc("")` are producing the same results, their standard library is well and truly broken, unless you've previously changed the global locale (e.g., with `setlocale`). The default ctor *should* create a locale that's a snapshot of the global locale. An empty string passed *should* create a locale based on the user's configuration of the OS (e.g., en-US locale for me, and fr-BE for a user with the OS configured for French/Belgium).

Comment: Or perhaps the "C" locale is configured by our sysadmin to mimic en_US